# Can you identify this insect for me?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Does anyone know what this is? I have lived in this area of northern Utah, USA for over 30 years and played with insects, snakes and spiders growing up here. However, until this week, I have never seen this insect before, nor anyone else we have asked. Suddenly they are all over our porch, patio, trampoline and house. This one is about the size of a lady bug, but we have seen some about double that size.

At first we thought it might be a beetle, but their shells are not bifurcated. Looking underneath, they have a long thin tube that they fold into their body that appears to be their mouths. We thought a weird tick, but they only have 6 legs. Can't seem to find anything similar online either.

Does anyone know, what it is?

[image: unknown insect]

Comment: I don't know about species in Utah, but this looks like a shield bug (Pentatomoidea) nymph. So perhaps that could get you somewhere in your search!

Comment: Since the back isn't bifurcated, not a beetle and with its long proboscis folded underneath, it's  a plant bug nymph (as in true bugs in the order *Hemiptera*). Suddenly finding them all over the place means eggs have recently hatched. Metamorphosis doesn't happen with true bugs. Eggs hatch directly into nymphs which are usually, but not always, a small version of the adult and go through a number of moults till adult. But I still don't know what species, sorry.

Comment: I found a bunch of similarly looking hatchlings on a plant on my balcony a few days ago. Probably a different species, given that I'm in France. It must be hatching season in the northern hemisphere.

Answer (score 8):

Definitely a nymph of some species of true bug (order [Hemiptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiptera)), most likely in the suborder [Heteroptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroptera) (i.e., the shield bugs, stink bugs, assassin bugs, etc.) and family [Pentatomidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatomidae).

For example, see these photos of nymphs of similar species:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

<sup>From L->R: [*Podisus maculiventris*](http://www.austinbug.com/survey/2011/survey4-28-2011.html), [*Troilus luridus*](https://www.britishbugs.org.uk/heteroptera/Pentatomidae/troilus_luridus.html), [*Glaucias amyoti*](http://www.landcareresearch.co.nz/resources/identification/animals/pentatomidae/key-to-nymphs), [*Cosmopepla lintneriana*](http://www.toronto-wildlife.com/Insects/True_Bugs/Plant_bugs/true_bugs_stink.html), [*Carpocoris purpureipennis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpocoris_purpureipennis), [*Murgantia histrionica*](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/veg/leaf/harlequin_bug.HTM)</sup>

Using yet another species, *Piezodorus lituratus*, as an example, you can see how a Pentatomidae nymph typically develops to maturity:

[image]

<sup>[Source](http://picssr.com/tags/nymfa/interesting/page25)</sup>

As to your species...

[This site](http://www.insectidentification.org/insects-by-type-and-region.asp?thisState=Utah&thisType=True%20Bug) lists *Cosmopepla lintneriana*, *Chinavia hilaris*, *Podisus placidus*, *Chlorochroa rossiana*, and *Sehirus cinctus* as species of Pentatomidae that live in Utah. None of their nymphs looks quite right, though your specimen reminds me most of a stripe-less *Podisus*. That might be a good jumping off place for further digging...

- As you can see, there are many species with similar nymphs, and various instars *within* species even have fairly great variation.

I can't find a great match yet, but I can keep looking. I'll update if I find one.

Comment: Plus, what with the shift in climate, insect ranges are shifting too, sometimes drastically.